# SHA1 calculation for millions of strings having common prefix

Tags: sha-1, performance

I have a function in which I need to calculate SHA1(common_prefix + random_string). I am calling this function many times so that calculation of SHA1 slows down the performance of the function. As for the all of the calls, I am using a common_prefix, is it possible to tweak SHA1 in a way that it won't calculate the hash for the (common_prefix+random_string), however it does something like a preprocessing for (common_prefix) and using this preprocess(calculated values) to calculate SHA1(common_prefix+random_string)?

Is it somehow possible to do it?

Comment: For reference, what are the respective bit lengths for common_prefix and random_string?

Comment: Use [blake](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/67549/18298) faster and more secure.

Comment: You should be extremely careful about using SHA-1!  SHA-1 has failed its original security goal of collision resistance.  You should use SHA-2, or SHA-3, or BLAKE2, unless you can prove that collision resistance is unnecessary for your application with reference to a design document articulating what your application does with what resources for whom and what its security goals are.

Comment: This is not intented for the purpose of security.
@PaulUszak length of common_prefix is 64 bytes and random_string length will be up to 8-9.

Comment: Yeh, no.  The question was to ascertain whether there is any point in bothering at all with multi-part hashing. Remember that SHAs come in fixed block sizes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, you can save effort, if the common prefix is at least one 512-bit block.**

Speaking mathematically: For a padded message $m = m_1 \mathbin\| m_2 \mathbin\| \cdots \mathbin\| m_\ell$ of $\ell$ 512-bit blocks, $$\operatorname{SHA1}(m) = f(\cdots f(f(\mathit{iv}, m_1), m_2) \cdots, m_\ell),$$ where $f$ is SHA-1's internal compression function.  For example, suppose you have a pair of two-block messages $m_1 \mathbin\| m_2$ and $m_1 \mathbin\| m_2'$ with a common prefix $m_1$ and distinct suffixes $m_2$ and $m_2'$.  Then

\begin{align}
  \operatorname{SHA1}(m_1 \mathbin\| m_2) &= f(f(\mathit{iv}, m_1), m_2), \\
  \operatorname{SHA1}(m_1 \mathbin\| m_2') &= f(f(\mathit{iv}, m_1), m_2'),
\end{align}

which share the common subexpression $f(\mathit{iv}, m_1)$.  If you precompute $h_0 = f(\mathit{iv}, m_1)$, then you can more quickly compute $\operatorname{SHA1}(m_1 \mathbin\| m_2) = f(h_0, m_2)$ and $\operatorname{SHA1}(m_1 \mathbin\| m_2') = f(h_0, m_2')$.

Speaking programmatically: Most implementations of SHA-1 support an init/update/final API.  For example, to hash the string `hello world` with OpenSSL's API you might write:

```
SHA_CTX ctx;
unsigned char h[20];

SHA1_Init(&ctx);
SHA1_Update(&ctx, "hello", 5);
SHA1_Update(&ctx, " ", 1);
SHA1_Update(&ctx, "world", 5);
SHA1_Final(h, &ctx);
```

The state of the SHA-1 computation, including buffering to split messages into blocks, is stored in the `SHA_CTX` object.  In some cases, like in OpenSSL, you can *copy* the context in order to save any effort that had already been done to hash what you've fed into it so far:

```
SHA_CTX ctx, ctx0, ctx1;
unsigned char h0[20], h1[20];

SHA1_Init(&ctx);
SHA1_Update(&ctx, "Once before a console dreary, while I programmed, weak and weary", 64);

ctx0 = ctx;
SHA1_Update(&ctx0, "\nOver many a curious program which did TECO's buffer fill...", 60);
SHA1_Final(h0, &ctx0);

ctx1 = ctx;
SHA1_Update(&ctx1, "\nO vermin yak urea's pro-Grammy itched dt casbah fur fell...", 60);
SHA1_Final(h1, &ctx1);
```

The resulting hashes are

- h0 = `b2b36d39d4431b3a57b7c30630bbbde9553b50ae`
- h1 = `2a0dae0548307b4ef33c0f1fedd7cbad2c32d5d8`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information.
I have tried out this way, however looks like the generated hash is not correct as I checked online.
The common_prefix was 64 'a' chars as following:
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.

Then I just added a letter 'w'. 
I used 64 'a' since you said it should be at least 512 bit length. Then the combined was incorrect. Do you know what might cause this?

Comment: The SHA-1 hash of the prefix is 0098ba824b5c16427bd7a1122a5a442a25ec644d, and the SHA-1 hash of the prefix with `w` added to it is 9deba23257f97a734f398132ad537d46b0913b94.  If your code isn't computing these, there's a bug in your code.  I don't know what code you're using, so I can't say what the bug is!

Comment: yes there was indeed a bug that I missed related to the size that I need to update. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 2):

[SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) processes data in blocks, see the following image:
[image: SHA-1 processing]

This means that common SHA-1 implementation provide the following three stateful functions:

- `Init()` - initialize the state to the IV
- `Update(data)` - append data to the input, the state for this may either come from `Init` or a previous `Update` call.
- `Final()` - computes the actual hash based on the state

Now this means that usually you would compute the SHA1 hash for your data in an object-oriented language as follows:

```
SHA1 instance(); // C++ notation
instance.Init();
instance.Update(common_prefix)
instance.Update(random_string)
return instance.Final()
```

Now all you have is to save and copy the internal state after the first `Update` call and re-use it across your differing instances. Of course be aware that no speedup is to be expected if the `common_prefix` is less than 512 bit, because in this case the internal compression function isn't invoked and all that happens is that the implementation will buffer the input.

Comment: FYI: This works for essentially all modern hash functions, but the threshold will be a different value.